# ValueError: exog is not 1d or 2d when trying to fit statsmodels OLS

Tags: python, numpy, statsmodels

I am trying to fit a simple OLS model using statsmodels by feeding in 2 numpy arrays that have column names. However on trying to fit the model I receive this error:

```
ValueError: exog is not 1d or 2d
```

To make the example reproducible I have used the sklearn dataset and created arrays. My code is as such:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn import datasets ## imports datasets from scikit-learn
data = datasets.load_boston() ## loads Boston dataset from datasets library

df = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=data.feature_names)
Y = pd.DataFrame(data.target, columns=["MEDV"])
Y = Y.to_numpy(dtype=[('MEDV', 'float64')])
X = df.to_numpy(dtype=[('CRIM', 'float64'), ('ZN', 'float64'), ('INDUS', 'float64'), ('CHAS', 'float64'), ('NOX', 'float64'),
                   ('RM', 'float64'), ('AGE', 'float64'), ('DIS', 'float64'), ('RAD', 'float64'), ('TAX', 'float64'),
                   ('PTRATIO', 'float64'), ('B', 'float64'), ('LSTAT', 'float64')])


model = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()
```

This does not make any sense as my Y variable is a vertical vector of numbers so it surely is 1D or 2D.

Does anyone understand why I am receiving this error?

Answer (score 1):

The simple fix is:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn import datasets ## imports datasets from scikit-learn
data = datasets.load_boston() ## loads Boston dataset from datasets library

df = pd.DataFrame(data.data, 
                  columns=data.feature_names)

Y = pd.DataFrame(data.target, columns=["MEDV"])

X = df.to_numpy()
Y = Y.to_numpy()

model = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()
```

Let's see the differences between the two approaches:

```py
Y = pd.DataFrame(data.target, columns=["MEDV"])

(Y.to_numpy(dtype=[('MEDV', 'float64')]))[:10]
array([[(24. ,)],
       [(21.6,)],
       [(34.7,)],
       [(33.4,)],
       [(36.2,)],
       [(28.7,)],
       [(22.9,)],
       [(27.1,)],
       [(16.5,)],
       [(18.9,)]], dtype=[('MEDV', '<f8')])
# That is an array of tuples

Y.to_numpy()[:10]
array([[24. ],
       [21.6],
       [34.7],
       [33.4],
       [36.2],
       [28.7],
       [22.9],
       [27.1],
       [16.5],
       [18.9]])
# This is an array of floats
```

The exact same happens for `X`.

Comment: Thanks. Will I still be able to call a numpy column by name with this approach?

Comment: Indeed you won't be able to do that. I suggest to store data with named columns in a dataframe, and pass to OLS the instances applying `.to_numpy()` directly in the parameters list

Comment: My problem there is I am restricted from using pandas at all here and therefore if I wanted to call a particular set of columns to feed into the OLS model, without using structured arrays, I can't see how it would work.

Comment: I see the problem of having an array of tuples though. Thanks

Comment: @geds133 I am not sure I am fully understanding your issue. If you cannot use pandas, maybe you could map column names to column indices, and define a function to subset columns given the array and the dictionary/mapping. Also try to print X as you defined it, I see quite a mess to be honest. Hope this helps