# Got ValueError: exog is not 1d or 2d when fitting OLS with a corner case

Tags: python, statsmodels

The following code causes an Exception to be raised.

```
>>> import statsmodels.api as sm
>>> sm.OLS(np.array([np.nan]), sm.add_constant(np.array([[1]]), has_constant="add"), missing="drop").fit().params

ValueError: exog is not 1d or 2d
```

Is there anyway to suppress the Exception and make the expression above return array([[nan., nan.]]) instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: exog is not 1d or 2d when trying to fit statsmodels OLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61647763/valueerror-exog-is-not-1d-or-2d-when-trying-to-fit-statsmodels-ols)

Comment: I checked and I don't think so.

Comment: statsmodels does not handle "empty" models. It's up to the user to provide "reasonable" data, and handle cases without "reasonable" data by themselves. What's reasonable data depends on the model, but almost all inferential statistics assume that number of observations is much larger than the number of parameters.